# Displaying Specific Data from mysql database based on user

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to have make it so if a user looks at their page they can see the assignments that they have either been working on or have completed.  Then I want to make it so that if they look at another users page they can see the projects that they have created.

```
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one = '$my_id' OR user_two = '$my_id'");
        while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)) {
            $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
            $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
            if($user_one == $my_id) {
                $user = $user_one;
            } else {
                $user = $user_two;
            }
            $username = getuser($user, 'username');
            echo "<a href = 'my_ideas.php?user=$user' class = 'list' style=display:block>Ideas</a>";

        ?>  
    <ul>

        <li><a href = '#my_links'>Linked Ideas</a></li>
        <li><a href = '#idea_chemistry'>My Idea Chemistry</a></li>
        <li><a href = 'settings.php'>Profile Settings</a></li>>
    </ul>
</div>

            <div id = 'my_projects'>

    <?php


            if($user != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
                $ideas_sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = $username";
                $query = mysql_query($ideas_sql) or die(mysql_error());
                $rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                do {
                ?>
                <h2><a href = 'edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $rsIdeas['id']; ?>'><?php echo $rsIdeas['name']; ?></a></h2>

                    <?php echo $rsIdeas['keywords']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['description']; ?></p>
                    <?php } while ($rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));


            } else {

            $ideas_sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = $my_id";
            $query = mysql_query($ideas_sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);   


            do {
            ?>
        <h2><a href = 'edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $rsIdeas['id']; ?>'><?php echo $rsIdeas['name']; ?></a></h2>

            <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['keywords']; ?></p>

            <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['description']; ?></p> 
            <?php } while ($rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)); 
                }
                     ?>
                <?php
                }

            ?>
```

I have googled this and searched for related questions on here but I cannot seem to find anything that helps with my problem.

Comment: This a example `$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one = '$my_id' OR user_two = '$my_id'") ` change this in `$frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one = '".$my_id"'' OR user_two = '".$my_id."'")`

Comment: Note the quotes and dots around the variables. You need to add them to your code.

Comment: would that fix the problem entirely or is there more I need to do.

Comment: No I don't think so. I see far more problems in your code, but you will need to start some where.

Comment: Thank you.  The only reason I ask because this displays data but only the data that the current logged in user has inputed.  I was wondering what I should do to get others users data on their profile page.

Comment: Can you explain you question further?

Comment: I am trying to take data from my database based on which user's page I am on.  For example, when I am on my page I want to see that data that corresponds with my user_id, and if I am on another user's page I want to see the data that corresponds with their user_id.  I have the process of retrieving data but no matter which user's page I am on only the data that the corresponds with the logged in user shows up.

Comment: So, some kind of admin view, where you want to see the friends of the user?

Comment: You could do this; Make a link to the profile page of a user. In this link you include the ID number for the user (e.g. `<a href="profifle.php?ID=1">Link to user 1</a>`). Do this with GET or save it in your session. Then on the next page you retrieve the ID with `$user_profile = $_GET['ID'];` or with the `$_SESSION['ID']`. Then instead of using `$my_id` you use `$user_profile` in the queries.

Comment: I already have variables $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; and $username = getuser($user, 'username');

Comment: I used these for the header where I have the name of the user displayed.

Comment: then insert the user id you want the data from in the query. this not your id so $my_id.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a code review question. There is also another site on SO network where you could place this type of question. Although you should show that you have some knowledge of coding.

I am not sure why there isn't a starting PHP tag, but here is the first part.

```
<?php

$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one = '".$my_id."' OR user_two = '".$my_id."'");
    while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)) {
        $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
        if($user_one == $my_id) {
            $user = $user_one;
        } else {
            $user = $user_two;
        }
        $username = getuser($user, 'username');
        echo "<a href = 'my_ideas.php?user='".$user."' class = 'list' style=display:block>Ideas</a>";

    ?>  
<ul>

    <li><a href = '#my_links'>Linked Ideas</a></li>
    <li><a href = '#idea_chemistry'>My Idea Chemistry</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'settings.php'>Profile Settings</a></li>>
</ul>



            <div id = 'my_projects'>

<?php


        if($user != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
            $ideas_sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = '".$username."'";
            $query = mysql_query($ideas_sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            do {
            ?>
            <h2><a href = 'edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $rsIdeas['id']; ?>'><?php echo $rsIdeas['name']; ?></a></h2>

                <?php echo $rsIdeas['keywords']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['description']; ?></p>
                <?php } while ($rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));


        } else {

        $ideas_sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id ='".$my_id."'";
        $query = mysql_query($ideas_sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);   


        do {
        ?>
    <h2><a href = 'edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $rsIdeas['id']; ?>'><?php echo $rsIdeas['name']; ?></a></h2>

        <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['keywords']; ?></p>

        <p><?php echo $rsIdeas['description']; ?></p> 
        <?php } while ($rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)); 
            }
                 ?>
            <?php
            }

        ?>
```

Question: Is this a custom function `getuser()`.

Comment: Yes that is a custom function. I'm sorry if it looks like a code review question but my real problem is when I run this no matter which users profile page I am on it only shows that data that the logged in user has inputed.  Also, I am not sure what happened with the 2 parts.  Thats just the way the question editor formatted it I guess.